# compare file names from one query against another query sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I am suppose to compare a document name from one query against query.

I have a table called tbl_doc which consists document_name column.

Another table called tbl_content which consists content_name.

And I have two select queries like

```
select document_name from tbl_doc

select content_name from tbl_content.
```

SO I need to compare document_name against content_name if they are equal then need to do a insert operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean to check if a certain value exists...

```
IF EXISTS( 
    SELECT 1 FROM [tbl_doc] 
    JOIN [tbl_content] ON [tbl_doc].[document_name] = [tbl_content].[content_name] 
    WHERE [tbl_doc].[document_name] = @Name )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [...]
    (
        ...
    )
    SELECT
        ...   
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select document_name,content_name
from tbl_doc
join tbl_content on document_name=content_name
```